# Chrome breaking Magento 2 checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.4, chrome-browser

This has started happening very recently with a new build of Chrome.
Checkout still works fine on Firefox, Safari, etc.

When you try to checkout you get an error at payment.

When "set-payment-information" is POSTed the email part of the payload is null.

Error message:
"email" is required. Enter and try again.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email variable value from mage cookie object and set that variable into object in new-customer-address file in magento/checkout/view/frontend/model.